# Как из формы получить значения из мультиселекта и отправить на почту?

Tags: php

Есть форма с мультиселектом. 
Как я понял мультиселект это массив с выбранными option. А как мне получить значения этих выбранных option? Нужно обойти массив и вывести данные, если есть? В php совсем 0(

```
<? 
$select = $_POST['select'];
$mail_message = '
<html>
<head>
    <title>Заявка</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>' .$select. '</h2>
';
?>
```

Если так выполнить то в письме приходит значение просто Array.

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам минимально воспроизводимый пример:

```
<form method="post">
    <select size="3" multiple name="select[]">
        <option disabled>Выберите значение</option>
        <option value="значение 1">значение 1</option>
        <option value="значение 2">значение 2</option>
        <option value="значение 3">значение 3</option>
        <option value="значение 4">значение 4</option>
        <option value="значение 5">значение 5</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>

<h2><?= join('<br>', $_POST['select'] ?? [])?></h2>
```

---

Что бы выбрать несколько значений из выпадающего списка, зажмите клавишу `Ctrl`, и кликните по нескольким строкам в списке *(они станут выделенными)*, и нажмите на кнопку "Отправить".

Так как в атрибуте `method=""` html-формы указан метод передачи `post`, то и принимать значения нужно в суперглобальном массиве `$_POST` - распечатайте его значения в браузере для визуального контроля, с помощью функции `print_r()`:

```
print_r($_POST['select']);
```

С помощью функции `join()` можно объединить элементы этого массива в строку, и сохранить их в переменной:

```
$select = join('<br>', $_POST['select'] ?? []);
```

Эту переменную теперь можно отправить на почту.